# Import oscilloscope measurements in Labview

Tags: interface, labview, oscilloscope

I am trying to interface an oscilloscope (RIGOL DS1054Z) with Labview, so far I have installed the IVI drivers from Rigol and use NI's example VI's that allow me to acquire a continuous waveform (similar to [this one](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-16512)).

Now I want to acquire some measurements displayed on the scope such as RMS voltage on channel 1, phase difference between channels 3 and 4 etc., something like what Ultrascope does, but it is not available on the example VIs. Does anyone have an idea?

I could process the channels on labviews but phase difference between two noisy signals is such a pain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, turns out I had to use SCPI commands and dig into the oscilloscope's programming guide [here](http://beyondmeasure.rigoltech.com/acton/attachment/1579/f-0386/1/-/-/-/-/DS1000Z_Programming%20Guide_EN.pdf). A preview of the code for displaying one channel and the phase difference between two others:

[image]

Comment: You don't need the sequence structure in this code. Dataflow will take care of what happens when.